I am getting errors creating and searching end users in Zendesk using Power Automate
I'll outline the intended purpose: we have a contact us form that sends an email when a submission is made. Currently this email is forwarded into a Zendesk support inbox to become. The agent then needs to manually fill out a lot of information in the Zendesk form using details in the email body. What we want to do is have the details in the email fill out the form automatically. We are aware that Zendesk has its own contact form that can be embedded into a web page, but that is not usable/suitable for this purpose.
The solution I figured we could use is have Power Automate receive the email instead, and then have it create the ticket. Potential hurdle: the person submitting the contact us form may already exist as an end user/customer in Zendesk. We need to first check if that person exists in Zendesk, and if so use that user ID as requester ID when creating the ticket. Otherwise if they don't exist; first create a new user, and use that new ID as the requester ID.
I haven't been able to figure out how to check for an existing user, I have tried a 'Get items' action but unsure how to set the filter query to search Zendesk by the customer's email address. I haven't yet gotten my head around how to structure ODATA queries, any thoughts on how to configure one to search Zendesk for existing end users?
When doing some testing trying to create a new end user using some dummy details I am getting an error. I am using the "Create Item" action, with the table name set to 'Users' (is this correct?) but it gives me the same error every time, "The value is not updatable". The parameters I am using are the minimum I think it needs, name and email. Does it require more to be successful?
My Power Automate flow is 2 steps, manually trigger the flow, then the Zendesk 'Create item' (and yes, it is signed in). Full text of the error output:
{ "status": 400, "message": "The value is not updatable.\r\n     inner exception: The value is not updatable.\r\nclientRequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", "error": { "message": "The value is not updatable.\r\n     inner exception: The value is not updatable." }, "source": "zendesk-ae.azconn-ae-001.p.azurewebsites.net" }
I know 400 basically means "user error", but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Has anyone had any success with creating and searching users in this manner? I should also add I am quite new to Power Automate and APIs.

I would avoid using the PowerAutomate Zendesk Integration, and go directly to the Zendesk API calls to have more freedom and flexibility.
To search a user by email, use the route /api/v2/search
and make a GET request, using this query
query=type:ticket user:example@example.com

The full URL would be like:
https://yoursubdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/search?query=type%3Aticket%20user%3Aexample%40example.com

To create a user, send a POST request to this route:
https://yoursubdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/users

With this body
{
  "user": {
        "name": "Mr. Example",
        "email": "example2@example.com"
    }
}

reference: https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/
